# How would I change the origin date of a pandas series that is of dtype datetime64[ns]?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, series

I have a pandas series that is of dtype datetime64[ns]. This is what it looks like:

```
0      1970-01-01 00:00:00
1      1970-01-01 00:00:01
2      1970-01-01 00:00:02
3      1970-01-01 00:00:03
4      1970-01-01 00:00:04
5      1970-01-01 00:00:05
6      1970-01-01 00:00:06
7      1970-01-01 00:00:07
8      1970-01-01 00:00:08
9      1970-01-01 00:00:09
10     1970-01-01 00:00:10
11     1970-01-01 00:00:11
12     1970-01-01 00:00:12
13     1970-01-01 00:00:13
14     1970-01-01 00:00:14
15     1970-01-01 00:00:15
16     1970-01-01 00:00:16
```

I would like to set my own origin date (the time portion of the datetime will remain the same), so that it looks like this instead:

```
0      2019-02-19 00:00:00
1      2019-02-19 00:00:01
2      2019-02-19 00:00:02
3      2019-02-19 00:00:03
4      2019-02-19 00:00:04
5      2019-02-19 00:00:05
6      2019-02-19 00:00:06
7      2019-02-19 00:00:07
8      2019-02-19 00:00:08
9      2019-02-19 00:00:09
10     2019-02-19 00:00:10
11     2019-02-19 00:00:11
12     2019-02-19 00:00:12
13     2019-02-19 00:00:13
14     2019-02-19 00:00:14
15     2019-02-19 00:00:15
16     2019-02-19 00:00:16
```

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your column is called `Date`, use [`Timestamp.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.replace.html):

```
df['Date'].apply(lambda dt: dt.replace(2019, 2, 19))
# or more self expalantory
# df['Date'].apply(lambda dt: dt.replace(year=2019, month=2, day=19))

0    2019-02-19 00:00:00
1    2019-02-19 00:00:01
2    2019-02-19 00:00:02
3    2019-02-19 00:00:03
4    2019-02-19 00:00:04
5    2019-02-19 00:00:05
6    2019-02-19 00:00:06
7    2019-02-19 00:00:07
8    2019-02-19 00:00:08
9    2019-02-19 00:00:09
10   2019-02-19 00:00:10
11   2019-02-19 00:00:11
12   2019-02-19 00:00:12
13   2019-02-19 00:00:13
14   2019-02-19 00:00:14
15   2019-02-19 00:00:15
16   2019-02-19 00:00:16
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want an arbitrary origin, you can sum the difference to that datetime:

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: x + datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 19) - datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1))
```